# How to approximate an AR(1) with an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a discrete stochastic process that can be described with the following equation

$$y_{(i+1)\tau}=k y_{i\tau}+w\xi_{i+1}$$

where $i\in\Bbb{N}$, $(\xi_i)_i$ is an IID sequence with $\xi_i \sim N(0,1)$, $0\ll\tau\in\Bbb{R}$, $0<k<1$ and $0<w\in\Bbb{R}$

And I want to approximate it with a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process. My final derivation is

$$dy=\frac{\ln{(k)}}{\tau}ydt+\frac{w}{\sqrt{\tau}}dW_t$$

where $W_t$ is the usual Wiener Process.

Is this correct?

---EDIT---

Following Calculon suggestions I came up with the following derivation.

Starting with the SDE.
$$dy_t = ay_tdt + bdW_t$$

The solution is
$$y_t = y_0e^{at} + be^{at}\int_0^te^{-as}dW_s$$

So we can see that
$$y_{t + \Delta t} = y_te^{a\Delta t} + be^{a\Delta t}\int_{0}^{\Delta t}e^{-as}dW_{t+s}$$
Thus it follows that
$$y_{(i+1)\tau} = y_{i\tau}e^{a\tau} + be^{a\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-as}dW_{t+s}$$

So we note that $$be^{a\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-as}dW_{t+s}\sim N\left(0,b^2e^{2a\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-2as}\,ds\right)=N\left(0,b^2\frac{e^{2a\tau}-1}{2a}\right)$$

So we rewrite
$$y_{(i+1)\tau} = e^{a\tau}y_{i\tau} + p\xi_{i+1}$$
where $(\xi_i)_i$ is an IID sequence of standard normal random variables and $p = \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{2a}(e^{2a\tau}-1)}$

So we match the coefficients $a$ and $b$ to $k$ and $w$ in my discrete-time model: $e^{a\tau} = k$ and $p = w$. Hence,
$$a = \frac{\log{k}}{\tau}$$
and
$$b = \frac{w}{\sqrt{\tau}}\sqrt{\frac{2\ln{k}}{k^2-1}}$$

Comment: On the RHS there should be $dt$ and $dW_t$ terms.

Comment: Edited! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, start with this SDE.
$$dy_t = ay_tdt + bdW_t \qquad \triangledown$$

The solution to this SDE is given by
$$y_t = y_0e^{at} + be^{at}\int_0^te^{-as}dW_s$$

We can write
$$y_{(i+1)\tau} = y_0e^{a(i+1)\tau} + be^{a(i+1)\tau}\int_{0}^{(i+1)\tau}e^{-as}dW_s \qquad \square$$
$$y_{i\tau} = y_0e^{ai\tau} + be^{ai\tau}\int_{0}^{i\tau}e^{-as}dW_s \qquad \triangle$$
Multiplying ($\triangle$) by $e^{a\tau}$ we get
$$e^{a\tau}y_{i\tau} = y_0e^{a(i+1)\tau} + be^{a(i+1)\tau}\int_{0}^{i\tau}e^{-as}dW_s \qquad \blacktriangle$$
Decomposing the stochastic integral in ($\square$) we get
$$y_{(i+1)\tau} = y_0e^{a(i+1)\tau} + be^{a(i+1)\tau}\int_{0}^{i\tau}e^{-as}dW_s+be^{a(i+1)\tau}\int_{i\tau}^{(i+1)\tau}e^{-as}dW_s \qquad \blacksquare$$

Now by $(\blacktriangle)$ and ($\blacksquare$) it follows that 
$$y_{(i+1)\tau} = e^{a\tau}y_{i\tau}+be^{a(i+1)\tau}\int_{i\tau}^{(i+1)\tau}e^{-as}dW_s \qquad \star$$
Note that
$$be^{a(i+1)\tau}\int_{i\tau}^{(i+1)\tau}e^{-as}dW_s\sim N(0,b^2e^{2a(i+1)\tau}\int_{i\tau}^{(i+1)\tau}e^{-2as}\,ds)$$
You can check yourself that
$$b^2e^{2a(i+1)\tau}\int_{i\tau}^{(i+1)\tau}e^{-2as}\,ds = \frac{b^2}{2a}(e^{2a\tau-1)}$$
Now rewrite ($\star$)  as
$$y_{(i+1)\tau} = e^{a\tau}y_{i\tau} + p\xi_{i+1} \qquad \bigstar$$
where $(\xi_i)_i$ is an IID sequence of standard normal random variables (why independent?) and $p = \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{2a}(e^{2a\tau}-1)}$

It is now possible to match the coefficients $a$ and $b$ to $k$ and $w$ in your discrete-time model. Clearly, $e^{a\tau} = k$ and $p = w$. Hence,
$$a = \frac{\log{k}}{\tau}$$
and
$$\lvert b\rvert = w\sqrt{\frac{2a}{e^{2a\tau}-1}}$$
Without loss of generality you can pick $b > 0$ (why?). Hence,

$$b = w\sqrt{\frac{2\log{k}}{\tau(k^2-1)}}$$

Note that if you start with the O-U process in ($\triangledown$) then the corresponding AR(1) process with the parameters prescribed above will be an *exact* discretization of the O-U process for any $\tau$.

Comment: My first thought was indeed to consider the Euler discretization, but the problem here is that $\tau \gg 0$ which I thought that would invalidate the approximation. Regarding the first approach, my $a$ agrees with your result, but I didn't get when you say: "you need to allow $w$ to depend on $i$ as the variance of [...] is time-varying. So an AR(1) model is too restrictive in this sense."

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, unfortunately I am having a hard time understanding what you wrote as it is going against my intuition. For me the following three sentences appear to be contradictory: 1. An Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process has the Markov Property. 2. Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process has a stationary distribution. 3. The variance term in the solution that you presented is time-varying. ... How can the variance be different for different $i$ if the process is Markovian?

Comment: @NunoCalaim There was an error in my previous answer. Sorry for the confusion. You can forget about the Markov stuff. Well actually don't forget about the Markov stuff but I had made an error while shifting the process in time. In my edited answer I derive the Markov property of the O-U process without taking it for granted. I hope it is clear to you now.

Comment: Your reply was indeed of much help, but I am still struggling with one part. I edited my question with the way I now think is correct after your suggestions. We reach a different conclusion, where did I go wrong?

Comment: @NunoCalaim "So we can see that
$$y_{t + \Delta t} = y_te^{a\Delta t} + be^{a\Delta t}\int_{0}^{\Delta t}e^{-as}dW_s$$" This is incorrect for several reasons. $y_{t + \Delta t}$ contains a stochastic integral term with respect to Brownian motion up until time $t + \Delta t$. You cannot just shift that integral in time like you do. Even if the integrand were constant, you wouldn't be able to do that, e.g. $cW_t = \int_0^t c dW_u  \neq \int_s^{t+s} c dW_u = cW_{t+s} - cW_s$ So in short, your starting point, which is based on your intuition, is wrong.

Comment: I understand that $\int_0^t c dW_u  \neq \int_s^{t+s} c dW_u$. But both quantities have the same distribution right? Namely both are normal random variables with mean $0$ and Variance $t$? I think my confusion, is that in some sense I am conditioning on the value of $y_{i\tau}$. When I write $y_{t + \Delta t} = y_te^{a\Delta t} + be^{a\Delta t}\int_{0}^{\Delta t}e^{-as}dW_s$ I am thinking that $y_{t + \Delta}$ is random but $y_t$ is known; Similar to defining a sequence by recursion. Does this make any sense? And THANK YOU so much for your time! I am learning!

Comment: Can you please double check on the correct value of $b$? Aren't you forgetting a square root, and inverting part of the expression?

Comment: @NunoCalaim You are right about the square root and the inversion. I corrected my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @NunoCalaim About the former comment, I understand your source of intuition. I had done something similar in my first answer. Since the O-U process is Markov, it restarts at every time instant. That should immediately allow you to write ($\star$). But I had made an error while the shifting the time. That is why in my edit I derived it from scratch (without assuming the Markov property). Likewise, the equality you wrote *sounds* correct (distributionally) but you would have to be very careful with things like that. Intuition, while being good for several reasons, can easily lead you astray.